# How to specify branch positions in tikz-qtree?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikz-trees, tikz-qtree

Using [`tikz-qtree`](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-qtree/tikz-qtree-manual.pdf), both branches are from 'S.south' (left figure). How to specify these branch positions manually (or automatically) as in the right figure?

[image: qtree-branch-position]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {draw, rectangle}]
  % using tikz-qtree: both branches are from "S.south"
  \Tree [.S [.NP ]
        [.VP ]
    ]

  % desired: both branches are not from ''s.south''
  \begin{scope}[xshift = 2.5cm]
    \node (s) {S};
    \node (np) [below left = 0.50cm and 0.05cm of s] {NP};
    \node (vp) [below right = 0.50cm and 0.05cm of s] {VP};
    \draw (s) to (np);
    \draw (s) to (vp);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out that

```
edge from parent/.style= {draw, 
     edge from parent path = {(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}}
```

works.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {draw, rectangle},
  edge from parent/.style= { % added code
    draw, edge from parent path = {(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}},]
  % using tikz-qtree
  \Tree [.S [.NP ]
        [.VP ]
    ]

  % desired: both branches do not come from ''s.south''
  \begin{scope}[xshift = 2.5cm]
    \node (s) {S};
    \node (np) [below left = 0.50cm and 0.05cm of s] {NP};
    \node (vp) [below right = 0.50cm and 0.05cm of s] {VP};
    \draw (s) to (np);
    \draw (s) to (vp);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```